# how to replace section of a bigcommerce checkout page with an iframe

Tags: javascript, json, bigcommerce

i am trying to remove a section of my bigcommerce checkout page and replace with an iframe... here is the portion of the checkout page i am trying to remove

```html
<div class="form-body">
    <ul class="form-checklist optimizedCheckout-form-checklist">
        <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item form-checklist-item--selected optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item--selected">
            <div class="form-checklist-header form-checklist-header--selected">
                <div class="form-field"><input name="paymentProviderRadio"
                                               class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox"
                                               id="radio-authorizenet" type="radio" value="authorizenet"
                                               checked=""><label for="radio-authorizenet"
                                                                 class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label"><span
                        class="paymentProviderHeader-name" data-test="payment-method-name">Credit Card</span>
                    <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc">
                        <ul class="creditCardTypes-list">
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium" data-test="credit-card-icon-visa"><svg
                                    height="100" viewBox="0 0 148 100" width="148" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g
                                    fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path
                                    d="M148 84c0 6.6-5.55 12-12 12H12C5.55 96 0 90.6 0 84V12C0 5.4 5.55 0 12 0h124c6.45 0 12 5.4 12 12v72z"
                                    fill="#F3F4F4"></path><path
                                    d="M0 24V12C0 5.4 5.74 0 12 0h124c6.26 0 12 5.4 12 12v12" fill="#01579F"></path><path
                                    d="M148 76v12c0 8.667-5.74 12-12 12H12c-6.26 0-12-3.333-12-12V76"
                                    fill="#FAA41D"></path><path
                                    d="M55.01 65.267l4.72-29.186h7.546l-4.72 29.19H55.01M89.913 36.8c-1.49-.59-3.85-1.242-6.77-1.242-7.452 0-12.7 3.974-12.73 9.656-.063 4.19 3.756 6.52 6.613 7.918 2.92 1.428 3.913 2.36 3.913 3.633-.04 1.957-2.36 2.857-4.54 2.857-3.014 0-4.628-.465-7.08-1.552l-.996-.466-1.055 6.55c1.77.808 5.03 1.52 8.415 1.553 7.92 0 13.075-3.912 13.137-9.967.03-3.322-1.987-5.868-6.334-7.948-2.64-1.336-4.256-2.236-4.256-3.602.032-1.242 1.367-2.514 4.348-2.514 2.453-.06 4.254.53 5.62 1.12l.684.31L89.91 36.8m10.03 18.13c.62-1.675 3.013-8.165 3.013-8.165-.03.062.62-1.707.994-2.794l.525 2.52s1.428 6.986 1.74 8.445H99.94zm9.317-18.846h-5.84c-1.8 0-3.17.53-3.945 2.424L88.265 65.27h7.918s1.305-3.6 1.585-4.377h9.687c.217 1.024.9 4.377.9 4.377h6.987l-6.082-29.19zm-60.555 0l-7.39 19.904-.807-4.037c-1.37-4.652-5.653-9.713-10.435-12.23l6.77 25.52h7.98L56.68 36.09H48.7"
                                    fill="#3B5CAA"></path><path
                                    d="M34.454 36.08H22.312l-.124.59c9.47 2.423 15.744 8.26 18.32 15.277L37.87 38.534c-.436-1.863-1.77-2.39-3.416-2.453"
                                    fill="#F8A51D"></path></g></svg></div></span></li>
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium" data-test="credit-card-icon-mastercard"><svg
                                    viewBox="0 0 131.39 86.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path
                                    d="M48.37 15.14h34.66v56.61H48.37z" fill="#ff5f00"></path><path
                                    d="M51.94 43.45a35.94 35.94 0 0113.75-28.3 36 36 0 100 56.61 35.94 35.94 0 01-13.75-28.31z"
                                    fill="#eb001b"></path><path
                                    d="M120.5 65.76V64.6h.5v-.24h-1.19v.24h.47v1.16zm2.31 0v-1.4h-.36l-.42 1-.42-1h-.36v1.4h.26V64.7l.39.91h.27l.39-.91v1.06zM123.94 43.45a36 36 0 01-58.25 28.3 36 36 0 000-56.61 36 36 0 0158.25 28.3z"
                                    fill="#f79e1b"></path></svg></div></span></li>
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                                    data-test="credit-card-icon-american-express"><svg height="104"
                                                                                       viewBox="0 0 156 104" width="156"
                                                                                       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g
                                    fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path
                                    d="M144 104H12c-6.15 0-12-5.85-12-12V12C0 5.85 5.85 0 12 0h132c6.15 0 12 5.85 12 12v80c0 6.15-5.85 12-12 12z"
                                    fill="#60C7EE"></path><g fill="#FFF"><path
                                    d="M95.05 46.532v3.68h12.93v4.723H95.05V59.5h12.79l5.244-6.824-4.673-6.144H95.05m-59.707 9.382h5.906l-2.97-8.324-2.94 8.324"></path><path
                                    d="M128.833 52.77l11.29-15.125h-19.067l-2.536 3.9-2.608-3.9h-46.59l-1.254 4.224-1.264-4.227H31.27L17.72 68.687h17.326l1.31-3.822h3.824l1.345 3.822h73.594l3.28-4.594 3.28 4.594h19.36l-4.867-6.343-7.342-9.574zM83.185 64.744H76.38v-17.66l-5.243 17.66h-6.16l-5.233-17.66v17.66H44.318l-1.345-3.823H33.54l-1.312 3.826h-8.483L33.85 41.588h9.065L52.94 64.56V41.59h10.927l4.214 14.09 4.187-14.09h10.92v23.156zm40.524 0l-5.31-7.44-5.31 7.44H86.72V41.588h27.085l4.76 7.124 4.63-7.124h9.062l-8.37 11.215 9.16 11.94h-9.338z"></path></g></g></svg></div></span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium" data-test="credit-card-icon-discover"><svg
                                    height="104" viewBox="0 0 152 104" width="152" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><rect height="104" id="a" rx="12"
                                                                                           width="152"></rect></defs><g
                                    fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><mask fill="#fff" id="b"><use xlink:href="#a"></use></mask><use
                                    fill="#F4F4F4" xlink:href="#a"></use><rect fill="#F4F4F4" height="104"
                                                                               mask="url(#b)" rx="12" width="152"
                                                                               x="1"></rect><path
                                    d="M70.553 104H149c2.21 0 4-1.783 4-4.007V46.597C142.305 71.907 111.28 93.04 70.553 104z"
                                    fill="#F76E20" mask="url(#b)"></path><g mask="url(#b)" transform="translate(19 42)"><path
                                    d="M14.763 9.22c0 2.94-.824 5.19-2.47 6.752-1.652 1.56-4.035 2.344-7.15 2.344H.155V.466H5.68c2.876 0 5.106.772 6.69 2.31C13.97 4.31 14.764 6.46 14.764 9.22zm-3.876.1c0-3.834-1.672-5.75-5.004-5.75h-1.99v11.62h1.602c3.596.002 5.392-1.957 5.392-5.87zM17.51 18.316V.466h3.733v17.85H17.51zM34.774 13.608c0 1.616-.57 2.88-1.718 3.81-1.146.927-2.734 1.397-4.773 1.397-1.874 0-3.54-.36-4.987-1.074v-3.516c1.19.543 2.196.915 3.017 1.14.822.218 1.577.327 2.26.327.815 0 1.446-.16 1.882-.475.43-.313.657-.792.657-1.413 0-.35-.095-.66-.292-.933-.188-.277-.474-.54-.85-.79-.374-.25-1.134-.657-2.28-1.21-1.073-.512-1.877-1.008-2.42-1.477-.542-.47-.967-1.018-1.288-1.65-.32-.63-.48-1.363-.48-2.2 0-1.577.526-2.818 1.582-3.72 1.06-.908 2.514-1.356 4.38-1.356.913 0 1.787.108 2.617.328.83.217 1.702.53 2.607.927l-1.203 2.942c-.94-.39-1.72-.67-2.334-.818-.616-.153-1.22-.232-1.81-.232-.71 0-1.254.164-1.627.502-.38.334-.567.768-.567 1.305 0 .335.076.623.23.875.152.25.395.487.728.72.332.23 1.125.647 2.366 1.25 1.643.8 2.77 1.6 3.384 2.4.613.796.92 1.778.92 2.943zM46.018 3.62c-1.406 0-2.49.54-3.263 1.605C41.98 6.295 41.6 7.79 41.6 9.7c0 3.978 1.473 5.97 4.418 5.97 1.238 0 2.727-.305 4.492-.94v3.175c-1.446.613-3.06.916-4.842.916-2.56 0-4.52-.79-5.875-2.367-1.357-1.572-2.034-3.834-2.034-6.782 0-1.855.335-3.48 1.003-4.874.662-1.402 1.623-2.467 2.87-3.212C42.884.84 44.345.467 46.022.467c1.71 0 3.43.42 5.152 1.258l-1.203 3.077c-.663-.317-1.32-.592-1.99-.83-.67-.238-1.322-.352-1.964-.352zM81.828.467h3.77l-5.98 17.85h-4.07L69.578.466h3.772l3.312 10.62c.182.632.38 1.356.572 2.195.19.836.316 1.408.368 1.737.087-.75.387-2.05.902-3.932L81.828.468zM97.072 18.316h-10.14V.466h10.14V3.57h-6.407v3.92h5.964v3.1h-5.965v4.6h6.407v3.126zM105.128 11.467v6.85h-3.732V.466h5.13c2.39 0 4.158.44 5.31 1.326 1.145.882 1.72 2.22 1.72 4.02 0 1.048-.286 1.987-.853 2.802-.57.82-1.376 1.46-2.418 1.925 2.647 4.007 4.37 6.603 5.175 7.773h-4.142l-4.203-6.85-1.987.004zm0-3.077h1.206c1.177 0 2.05-.2 2.612-.596.558-.402.842-1.03.842-1.883 0-.847-.29-1.445-.862-1.806-.573-.36-1.46-.537-2.664-.537h-1.14l.006 4.823z"
                                    fill="#414042"></path><ellipse cx="61.024" cy="9.393" fill="#F76E20" rx="8.802"
                                                                   ry="8.926"></ellipse></g></g></svg></div></span></li>
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium" data-test="credit-card-icon-diners-club"><svg
                                    height="104" viewBox="0 0 152 104" width="152" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><rect height="104" id="a" rx="12"
                                                                                           width="152"></rect></defs><g
                                    fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><mask fill="#fff" id="b"><use xlink:href="#a"></use></mask><use
                                    fill="#F4F4F4" xlink:href="#a"></use><rect fill="#F4F4F4" height="104"
                                                                               mask="url(#b)" rx="12" width="152"
                                                                               x="1"></rect><g
                                    transform="translate(42 26)"><ellipse cx="26.716" cy="26" fill="#009FDA" rx="26"
                                                                          ry="26"></ellipse><path
                                    d="M24.116 0c13 0 25.997 11.643 25.997 26 0 14.355-12.997 26-25.997 26V0z"
                                    fill="#009FDA"></path><path
                                    d="M24.116 52V0H42.75c13 0 25.997 11.643 25.997 26 0 14.355-12.997 26-25.997 26H24.116z"
                                    fill="#009FDA"></path><circle cx="25.255" cy="27.139" fill="#F3F4F4"
                                                                  r="24.539"></circle><path
                                    d="M38.255 24.983c0-7.09-6.34-13.02-11.54-14.583v29.167c5.2-1.563 11.54-7.488 11.54-14.584zM5.916 24.986c0 7.09 6.34 13.02 11.54 14.583V10.4c-5.2 1.565-11.54 7.493-11.54 14.586z"
                                    fill="#009FDA"></path></g></g></svg></div></span></li>
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium" data-test="credit-card-icon-jcb"><svg
                                    clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                    stroke-miterlimit="1.4" viewBox="0 0 480 301" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path
                                    d="M444 0H24C12 0 0 12 0 24v240.1c0 24 12 36 36 36h408c24 0 36-12 36-36v-228C480 12 468 0 444 0z"
                                    fill="#f4f4f4"></path><path
                                    d="M314.8 174.9h21.5l2.7-.2c4-.8 7.6-4.5 7.6-9.6 0-5-3.5-8.6-7.6-9.6l-2.7-.3h-21.5V175z"
                                    fill="#469951" fill-rule="nonzero"></path><path
                                    d="M333.9 39.2a37.3 37.3 0 0 0-37.3 37.2v38.7h52.6c1.2 0 2.7 0 3.7.2 11.9.7 20.7 6.8 20.7 17.4 0 8.4-6 15.6-17 17v.4c12 .8 21.3 7.6 21.3 18 0 11.3-10.3 18.7-23.8 18.7h-57.7v75.7h54.7a37.3 37.3 0 0 0 37.2-37.3v-186H334z"
                                    fill="#469951" fill-rule="nonzero"></path><path
                                    d="M343.9 135.2c0-5-3.5-8.2-7.6-8.8l-2-.2h-19.5v18h19.5c.3 0 1.4 0 2-.2 4.1-.6 7.6-3.9 7.6-8.8z"
                                    fill="#469951" fill-rule="nonzero"></path><path
                                    d="M128 39.2a37.3 37.3 0 0 0-37.3 37.2v92a73.7 73.7 0 0 0 32.2 8.3c12.8 0 19.8-7.7 19.8-18.4V115h32v43.2c0 16.8-10.5 30.5-46 30.5-21.4 0-38.2-4.7-38.2-4.7v78.4h54.7a37.3 37.3 0 0 0 37.2-37.3V39.2H128z"
                                    fill="#245797" fill-rule="nonzero"></path><path
                                    d="M231 39.2a37.3 37.3 0 0 0-37.3 37.2v48.8c9.4-8 25.8-13.1 52.2-12 14 .7 29.2 4.6 29.2 4.6v15.8a70.9 70.9 0 0 0-28.2-8.2c-20-1.5-32.1 8.4-32.1 25.5 0 17.4 12 27.3 32 25.6a74.3 74.3 0 0 0 28.3-8.2v15.8s-15 3.9-29.2 4.5c-26.4 1.2-42.8-3.9-52.2-11.9v86h54.6a37.3 37.3 0 0 0 37.3-37.3V39.2h-54.7z"
                                    fill="#ca4638" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></div></span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-checklist-body">
                <div style="">
                    <div class="paymentMethod paymentMethod--creditCard">
                        <fieldset class="form-fieldset creditCardFieldset">
                            <legend class="form-legend is-srOnly">Credit card</legend>
                            <div class="form-body">
                                <div class="form-ccFields">
                                    <div class="form-field form-field--ccNumber"><label for="ccNumber"
                                                                                        class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">Credit
                                        Card Number</label><input name="ccNumber" autocomplete="cc-number" id="ccNumber"
                                                                  class="form-input optimizedCheckout-form-input has-icon"
                                                                  type="tel" value="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"
                                                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path d="M18 8h-1V6c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5S7 3.24 7 6v2H6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V10c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-6 9c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm3.1-9H8.9V6c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1 1.71 0 3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1v2z"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-field form-field--ccExpiry"><label for="ccExpiry"
                                                                                        class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">Expiration</label><input
                                            name="ccExpiry" autocomplete="cc-exp" id="ccExpiry" placeholder="MM / YY"
                                            class="form-input optimizedCheckout-form-input" type="tel" value=""></div>
                                    <div class="form-field form-field--ccName"><label for="ccName"
                                                                                      class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">Name
                                        on Card</label><input name="ccName" autocomplete="cc-name" id="ccName"
                                                              class="form-input optimizedCheckout-form-input"
                                                              type="text" value=""></div>
                                    <div class="form-field form-ccFields-field--ccCvv"><label for="ccCvv"
                                                                                              class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">CVV<span><span
                                            class="has-tip"><div class="icon"><svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                                                   width="24"
                                                                                   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path
                                            d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 17h-2v-2h2v2zm2.07-7.75l-.9.92C13.45 12.9 13 13.5 13 15h-2v-.5c0-1.1.45-2.1 1.17-2.83l1.24-1.26c.37-.36.59-.86.59-1.41 0-1.1-.9-2-2-2s-2 .9-2 2H8c0-2.21 1.79-4 4-4s4 1.79 4 4c0 .88-.36 1.68-.93 2.25z"></path></svg></div></span></span></label><input
                                            name="ccCvv" autocomplete="cc-csc" id="ccCvv"
                                            class="form-input optimizedCheckout-form-input has-icon" type="tel"
                                            value="">
                                        <div class="icon">
                                            <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"
                                                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path d="M18 8h-1V6c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5S7 3.24 7 6v2H6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V10c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-6 9c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm3.1-9H8.9V6c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1 1.71 0 3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1v2z"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item">
            <div class="form-checklist-header">
                <div class="form-field"><input name="paymentProviderRadio"
                                               class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox"
                                               id="radio-paypalexpress" type="radio" value="paypalexpress"><label
                        for="radio-paypalexpress" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label"><img alt="PayPal"
                                                                                                       class="paymentProviderHeader-img"
                                                                                                       data-test="payment-method-logo"
                                                                                                       src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/r-a27911b5d209595e667e9db480b43ab34afcf74d/img/payment-providers/paypalpaymentsprouk.png">
                    <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc">
                        <ul class="creditCardTypes-list">
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium" data-test="credit-card-icon-visa"><svg
                                    height="100" viewBox="0 0 148 100" width="148" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g
                                    fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path
                                    d="M148 84c0 6.6-5.55 12-12 12H12C5.55 96 0 90.6 0 84V12C0 5.4 5.55 0 12 0h124c6.45 0 12 5.4 12 12v72z"
                                    fill="#F3F4F4"></path><path
                                    d="M0 24V12C0 5.4 5.74 0 12 0h124c6.26 0 12 5.4 12 12v12" fill="#01579F"></path><path
                                    d="M148 76v12c0 8.667-5.74 12-12 12H12c-6.26 0-12-3.333-12-12V76"
                                    fill="#FAA41D"></path><path
                                    d="M55.01 65.267l4.72-29.186h7.546l-4.72 29.19H55.01M89.913 36.8c-1.49-.59-3.85-1.242-6.77-1.242-7.452 0-12.7 3.974-12.73 9.656-.063 4.19 3.756 6.52 6.613 7.918 2.92 1.428 3.913 2.36 3.913 3.633-.04 1.957-2.36 2.857-4.54 2.857-3.014 0-4.628-.465-7.08-1.552l-.996-.466-1.055 6.55c1.77.808 5.03 1.52 8.415 1.553 7.92 0 13.075-3.912 13.137-9.967.03-3.322-1.987-5.868-6.334-7.948-2.64-1.336-4.256-2.236-4.256-3.602.032-1.242 1.367-2.514 4.348-2.514 2.453-.06 4.254.53 5.62 1.12l.684.31L89.91 36.8m10.03 18.13c.62-1.675 3.013-8.165 3.013-8.165-.03.062.62-1.707.994-2.794l.525 2.52s1.428 6.986 1.74 8.445H99.94zm9.317-18.846h-5.84c-1.8 0-3.17.53-3.945 2.424L88.265 65.27h7.918s1.305-3.6 1.585-4.377h9.687c.217 1.024.9 4.377.9 4.377h6.987l-6.082-29.19zm-60.555 0l-7.39 19.904-.807-4.037c-1.37-4.652-5.653-9.713-10.435-12.23l6.77 25.52h7.98L56.68 36.09H48.7"
                                    fill="#3B5CAA"></path><path
                                    d="M34.454 36.08H22.312l-.124.59c9.47 2.423 15.744 8.26 18.32 15.277L37.87 38.534c-.436-1.863-1.77-2.39-3.416-2.453"
                                    fill="#F8A51D"></path></g></svg></div></span></li>
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium" data-test="credit-card-icon-mastercard"><svg
                                    viewBox="0 0 131.39 86.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path
                                    d="M48.37 15.14h34.66v56.61H48.37z" fill="#ff5f00"></path><path
                                    d="M51.94 43.45a35.94 35.94 0 0113.75-28.3 36 36 0 100 56.61 35.94 35.94 0 01-13.75-28.31z"
                                    fill="#eb001b"></path><path
                                    d="M120.5 65.76V64.6h.5v-.24h-1.19v.24h.47v1.16zm2.31 0v-1.4h-.36l-.42 1-.42-1h-.36v1.4h.26V64.7l.39.91h.27l.39-.91v1.06zM123.94 43.45a36 36 0 01-58.25 28.3 36 36 0 000-56.61 36 36 0 0158.25 28.3z"
                                    fill="#f79e1b"></path></svg></div></span></li>
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium" data-test="credit-card-icon-discover"><svg
                                    height="104" viewBox="0 0 152 104" width="152" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><rect height="104" id="a" rx="12"
                                                                                           width="152"></rect></defs><g
                                    fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><mask fill="#fff" id="b"><use xlink:href="#a"></use></mask><use
                                    fill="#F4F4F4" xlink:href="#a"></use><rect fill="#F4F4F4" height="104"
                                                                               mask="url(#b)" rx="12" width="152"
                                                                               x="1"></rect><path
                                    d="M70.553 104H149c2.21 0 4-1.783 4-4.007V46.597C142.305 71.907 111.28 93.04 70.553 104z"
                                    fill="#F76E20" mask="url(#b)"></path><g mask="url(#b)" transform="translate(19 42)"><path
                                    d="M14.763 9.22c0 2.94-.824 5.19-2.47 6.752-1.652 1.56-4.035 2.344-7.15 2.344H.155V.466H5.68c2.876 0 5.106.772 6.69 2.31C13.97 4.31 14.764 6.46 14.764 9.22zm-3.876.1c0-3.834-1.672-5.75-5.004-5.75h-1.99v11.62h1.602c3.596.002 5.392-1.957 5.392-5.87zM17.51 18.316V.466h3.733v17.85H17.51zM34.774 13.608c0 1.616-.57 2.88-1.718 3.81-1.146.927-2.734 1.397-4.773 1.397-1.874 0-3.54-.36-4.987-1.074v-3.516c1.19.543 2.196.915 3.017 1.14.822.218 1.577.327 2.26.327.815 0 1.446-.16 1.882-.475.43-.313.657-.792.657-1.413 0-.35-.095-.66-.292-.933-.188-.277-.474-.54-.85-.79-.374-.25-1.134-.657-2.28-1.21-1.073-.512-1.877-1.008-2.42-1.477-.542-.47-.967-1.018-1.288-1.65-.32-.63-.48-1.363-.48-2.2 0-1.577.526-2.818 1.582-3.72 1.06-.908 2.514-1.356 4.38-1.356.913 0 1.787.108 2.617.328.83.217 1.702.53 2.607.927l-1.203 2.942c-.94-.39-1.72-.67-2.334-.818-.616-.153-1.22-.232-1.81-.232-.71 0-1.254.164-1.627.502-.38.334-.567.768-.567 1.305 0 .335.076.623.23.875.152.25.395.487.728.72.332.23 1.125.647 2.366 1.25 1.643.8 2.77 1.6 3.384 2.4.613.796.92 1.778.92 2.943zM46.018 3.62c-1.406 0-2.49.54-3.263 1.605C41.98 6.295 41.6 7.79 41.6 9.7c0 3.978 1.473 5.97 4.418 5.97 1.238 0 2.727-.305 4.492-.94v3.175c-1.446.613-3.06.916-4.842.916-2.56 0-4.52-.79-5.875-2.367-1.357-1.572-2.034-3.834-2.034-6.782 0-1.855.335-3.48 1.003-4.874.662-1.402 1.623-2.467 2.87-3.212C42.884.84 44.345.467 46.022.467c1.71 0 3.43.42 5.152 1.258l-1.203 3.077c-.663-.317-1.32-.592-1.99-.83-.67-.238-1.322-.352-1.964-.352zM81.828.467h3.77l-5.98 17.85h-4.07L69.578.466h3.772l3.312 10.62c.182.632.38 1.356.572 2.195.19.836.316 1.408.368 1.737.087-.75.387-2.05.902-3.932L81.828.468zM97.072 18.316h-10.14V.466h10.14V3.57h-6.407v3.92h5.964v3.1h-5.965v4.6h6.407v3.126zM105.128 11.467v6.85h-3.732V.466h5.13c2.39 0 4.158.44 5.31 1.326 1.145.882 1.72 2.22 1.72 4.02 0 1.048-.286 1.987-.853 2.802-.57.82-1.376 1.46-2.418 1.925 2.647 4.007 4.37 6.603 5.175 7.773h-4.142l-4.203-6.85-1.987.004zm0-3.077h1.206c1.177 0 2.05-.2 2.612-.596.558-.402.842-1.03.842-1.883 0-.847-.29-1.445-.862-1.806-.573-.36-1.46-.537-2.664-.537h-1.14l.006 4.823z"
                                    fill="#414042"></path><ellipse cx="61.024" cy="9.393" fill="#F76E20" rx="8.802"
                                                                   ry="8.926"></ellipse></g></g></svg></div></span></li>
                            <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                                    class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                                    data-test="credit-card-icon-american-express"><svg height="104"
                                                                                       viewBox="0 0 156 104" width="156"
                                                                                       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g
                                    fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path
                                    d="M144 104H12c-6.15 0-12-5.85-12-12V12C0 5.85 5.85 0 12 0h132c6.15 0 12 5.85 12 12v80c0 6.15-5.85 12-12 12z"
                                    fill="#60C7EE"></path><g fill="#FFF"><path
                                    d="M95.05 46.532v3.68h12.93v4.723H95.05V59.5h12.79l5.244-6.824-4.673-6.144H95.05m-59.707 9.382h5.906l-2.97-8.324-2.94 8.324"></path><path
                                    d="M128.833 52.77l11.29-15.125h-19.067l-2.536 3.9-2.608-3.9h-46.59l-1.254 4.224-1.264-4.227H31.27L17.72 68.687h17.326l1.31-3.822h3.824l1.345 3.822h73.594l3.28-4.594 3.28 4.594h19.36l-4.867-6.343-7.342-9.574zM83.185 64.744H76.38v-17.66l-5.243 17.66h-6.16l-5.233-17.66v17.66H44.318l-1.345-3.823H33.54l-1.312 3.826h-8.483L33.85 41.588h9.065L52.94 64.56V41.59h10.927l4.214 14.09 4.187-14.09h10.92v23.156zm40.524 0l-5.31-7.44-5.31 7.44H86.72V41.588h27.085l4.76 7.124 4.63-7.124h9.062l-8.37 11.215 9.16 11.94h-9.338z"></path></g></g></svg></div></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item">
            <div class="form-checklist-header">
                <div class="form-field"><input name="paymentProviderRadio"
                                               class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox"
                                               id="radio-affirm" type="radio" value="affirm"><label for="radio-affirm"
                                                                                                    class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label"><img
                        alt="Affirm" class="paymentProviderHeader-img" data-test="payment-method-logo"
                        src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/r-a27911b5d209595e667e9db480b43ab34afcf74d/img/payment-providers/affirm-checkout-header.png"><span
                        class="paymentProviderHeader-name" data-test="payment-method-name">Monthly Payments</span>
                    <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc"></div>
                </label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and replace with iframe form like this

```html
<iframe src="www.example.com" style="border:none" scrolling="no" width="400px" height="500px"></iframe>
```

can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: What's the purpose of using an iframe? If it's simply to get a scrollable view, why not just use a scrollable div?

Comment: no it is a plugin for a superior payment method not just for scrolling i only have that so the plugin fits to size in the area

Comment: i want to remove the old payment method and replace with an iframe linked to bitcoin payment which bigcommerce doesnt have and i am wanting to make it a script that anyone can add to their site backend so they can accept bitcoin also, i have all the coding done to interact with bigcommerce i just need to embed it on the checkout page properly

Comment: Is my revised answer below acceptable?

Comment: What problem are you having specifically? Adding an iframe element to a web page is trivial, but there are browser security mechanisms that will prevent an iframe from loading in certain situations. For instance the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header. Your question is too vague in it's current state, please add specific details about what exactly is not working for you.

Comment: i am trying to do replace the current checkout payment options with a customized checkout that i can allow others to use as well

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to replace the credit card section of a form:

```html
<form>
  ...
  <div class="form-body">
    ...
    Credit Card
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

with a single `<iframe>` element.

This code will locate within a `<form>` the `<div class="form-body">`  containing the text "Credit Card", replacing it with an `<iframe>`:

```js
  // find div that:
  // - is a child of <form> element
  // - has the class "form-body"
  // - contains the text "Credit Card"
  function findFormBodyWithCreditCard () {
    const form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    const formChildren = Array.from(form.children);

    const ccDiv = formChildren.reduce((accDiv, div) => {
      if (accDiv) { return accDiv; }

      // reject if not "form-body"
      if (!div.classList.contains('form-body')) { return null; }

      // reject if missing "Credit Card" text
      if (!div.innerText.includes('Credit Card')) { return null; }

      return div;
    }, null);

    return ccDiv;
  }

  function replaceFormBodyWithIframe () {
    let ccDiv = findFormBodyWithCreditCard ();

    if (!ccDiv) {
      alert('credit card section not found');
      return;
    }

    let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = 'https://www.example.com';
    iframe.style.border = '1px solid #bbb';
    iframe.height = '300px';
    ccDiv.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', iframe);
    ccDiv.remove();
  }
```

```css
.form-body {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
}

svg {
  display: none;
}

form {
  margin: 1rem 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #eee;
}

form:before {
  color: #aaa;
  content: "<form>"
}

form:after {
  color: #aaa;
  content: "</form>"
}
```

```html
<h4>Replace "form-body" div containing "Credit Card" with an iframe</h4>
<button onclick="replaceFormBodyWithIframe()">Replace</button><br/>

<form>
  <div class="form-body">.form-body</div>
  <div class="form-body">.form-body</div>
  <div class="form-body">
    <ul class="form-checklist optimizedCheckout-form-checklist">
      <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item form-checklist-item--selected optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item--selected">
        <div class="form-checklist-header form-checklist-header--selected">
          <div class="form-field"><input name="paymentProviderRadio" class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox" id="radio-authorizenet" type="radio" value="authorizenet" checked=""><label for="radio-authorizenet" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label"><span
            class="paymentProviderHeader-name" data-test="payment-method-name">Credit Card</span>
            <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc">
              <ul class="creditCardTypes-list">
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-visa"><svg
                  height="100" viewBox="0 0 148 100" width="148"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g
                  fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path
                  d="M148 84c0 6.6-5.55 12-12 12H12C5.55 96 0 90.6 0 84V12C0 5.4 5.55 0 12 0h124c6.45 0 12 5.4 12 12v72z"
                  fill="#F3F4F4"></path><path
                  d="M0 24V12C0 5.4 5.74 0 12 0h124c6.26 0 12 5.4 12 12v12"
                  fill="#01579F"></path><path
                  d="M148 76v12c0 8.667-5.74 12-12 12H12c-6.26 0-12-3.333-12-12V76"
                  fill="#FAA41D"></path><path
                  d="M55.01 65.267l4.72-29.186h7.546l-4.72 29.19H55.01M89.913 36.8c-1.49-.59-3.85-1.242-6.77-1.242-7.452 0-12.7 3.974-12.73 9.656-.063 4.19 3.756 6.52 6.613 7.918 2.92 1.428 3.913 2.36 3.913 3.633-.04 1.957-2.36 2.857-4.54 2.857-3.014 0-4.628-.465-7.08-1.552l-.996-.466-1.055 6.55c1.77.808 5.03 1.52 8.415 1.553 7.92 0 13.075-3.912 13.137-9.967.03-3.322-1.987-5.868-6.334-7.948-2.64-1.336-4.256-2.236-4.256-3.602.032-1.242 1.367-2.514 4.348-2.514 2.453-.06 4.254.53 5.62 1.12l.684.31L89.91 36.8m10.03 18.13c.62-1.675 3.013-8.165 3.013-8.165-.03.062.62-1.707.994-2.794l.525 2.52s1.428 6.986 1.74 8.445H99.94zm9.317-18.846h-5.84c-1.8 0-3.17.53-3.945 2.424L88.265 65.27h7.918s1.305-3.6 1.585-4.377h9.687c.217 1.024.9 4.377.9 4.377h6.987l-6.082-29.19zm-60.555 0l-7.39 19.904-.807-4.037c-1.37-4.652-5.653-9.713-10.435-12.23l6.77 25.52h7.98L56.68 36.09H48.7"
                  fill="#3B5CAA"></path><path
                  d="M34.454 36.08H22.312l-.124.59c9.47 2.423 15.744 8.26 18.32 15.277L37.87 38.534c-.436-1.863-1.77-2.39-3.416-2.453"
                  fill="#F8A51D"></path></g></svg></div></span></li>
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-mastercard"><svg
                  viewBox="0 0 131.39 86.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path
                  d="M48.37 15.14h34.66v56.61H48.37z" fill="#ff5f00"></path><path
                  d="M51.94 43.45a35.94 35.94 0 0113.75-28.3 36 36 0 100 56.61 35.94 35.94 0 01-13.75-28.31z"
                  fill="#eb001b"></path><path
                  d="M120.5 65.76V64.6h.5v-.24h-1.19v.24h.47v1.16zm2.31 0v-1.4h-.36l-.42 1-.42-1h-.36v1.4h.26V64.7l.39.91h.27l.39-.91v1.06zM123.94 43.45a36 36 0 01-58.25 28.3 36 36 0 000-56.61 36 36 0 0158.25 28.3z"
                  fill="#f79e1b"></path></svg></div></span></li>
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-american-express"><svg height="104"
                                                                     viewBox="0 0 156 104"
                                                                     width="156"
                                                                     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g
                  fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path
                  d="M144 104H12c-6.15 0-12-5.85-12-12V12C0 5.85 5.85 0 12 0h132c6.15 0 12 5.85 12 12v80c0 6.15-5.85 12-12 12z"
                  fill="#60C7EE"></path><g fill="#FFF"><path
                  d="M95.05 46.532v3.68h12.93v4.723H95.05V59.5h12.79l5.244-6.824-4.673-6.144H95.05m-59.707 9.382h5.906l-2.97-8.324-2.94 8.324"></path><path
                  d="M128.833 52.77l11.29-15.125h-19.067l-2.536 3.9-2.608-3.9h-46.59l-1.254 4.224-1.264-4.227H31.27L17.72 68.687h17.326l1.31-3.822h3.824l1.345 3.822h73.594l3.28-4.594 3.28 4.594h19.36l-4.867-6.343-7.342-9.574zM83.185 64.744H76.38v-17.66l-5.243 17.66h-6.16l-5.233-17.66v17.66H44.318l-1.345-3.823H33.54l-1.312 3.826h-8.483L33.85 41.588h9.065L52.94 64.56V41.59h10.927l4.214 14.09 4.187-14.09h10.92v23.156zm40.524 0l-5.31-7.44-5.31 7.44H86.72V41.588h27.085l4.76 7.124 4.63-7.124h9.062l-8.37 11.215 9.16 11.94h-9.338z"></path></g></g></svg></div></span>
                </li>
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-discover"><svg
                  height="104" viewBox="0 0 152 104" width="152"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><rect
                  height="104" id="a" rx="12"
                  width="152"></rect></defs><g
                  fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><mask fill="#fff" id="b"><use
                  xlink:href="#a"></use></mask><use
                  fill="#F4F4F4" xlink:href="#a"></use><rect fill="#F4F4F4"
                                                             height="104"
                                                             mask="url(#b)"
                                                             rx="12" width="152"
                                                             x="1"></rect><path
                  d="M70.553 104H149c2.21 0 4-1.783 4-4.007V46.597C142.305 71.907 111.28 93.04 70.553 104z"
                  fill="#F76E20" mask="url(#b)"></path><g mask="url(#b)"
                                                          transform="translate(19 42)"><path
                  d="M14.763 9.22c0 2.94-.824 5.19-2.47 6.752-1.652 1.56-4.035 2.344-7.15 2.344H.155V.466H5.68c2.876 0 5.106.772 6.69 2.31C13.97 4.31 14.764 6.46 14.764 9.22zm-3.876.1c0-3.834-1.672-5.75-5.004-5.75h-1.99v11.62h1.602c3.596.002 5.392-1.957 5.392-5.87zM17.51 18.316V.466h3.733v17.85H17.51zM34.774 13.608c0 1.616-.57 2.88-1.718 3.81-1.146.927-2.734 1.397-4.773 1.397-1.874 0-3.54-.36-4.987-1.074v-3.516c1.19.543 2.196.915 3.017 1.14.822.218 1.577.327 2.26.327.815 0 1.446-.16 1.882-.475.43-.313.657-.792.657-1.413 0-.35-.095-.66-.292-.933-.188-.277-.474-.54-.85-.79-.374-.25-1.134-.657-2.28-1.21-1.073-.512-1.877-1.008-2.42-1.477-.542-.47-.967-1.018-1.288-1.65-.32-.63-.48-1.363-.48-2.2 0-1.577.526-2.818 1.582-3.72 1.06-.908 2.514-1.356 4.38-1.356.913 0 1.787.108 2.617.328.83.217 1.702.53 2.607.927l-1.203 2.942c-.94-.39-1.72-.67-2.334-.818-.616-.153-1.22-.232-1.81-.232-.71 0-1.254.164-1.627.502-.38.334-.567.768-.567 1.305 0 .335.076.623.23.875.152.25.395.487.728.72.332.23 1.125.647 2.366 1.25 1.643.8 2.77 1.6 3.384 2.4.613.796.92 1.778.92 2.943zM46.018 3.62c-1.406 0-2.49.54-3.263 1.605C41.98 6.295 41.6 7.79 41.6 9.7c0 3.978 1.473 5.97 4.418 5.97 1.238 0 2.727-.305 4.492-.94v3.175c-1.446.613-3.06.916-4.842.916-2.56 0-4.52-.79-5.875-2.367-1.357-1.572-2.034-3.834-2.034-6.782 0-1.855.335-3.48 1.003-4.874.662-1.402 1.623-2.467 2.87-3.212C42.884.84 44.345.467 46.022.467c1.71 0 3.43.42 5.152 1.258l-1.203 3.077c-.663-.317-1.32-.592-1.99-.83-.67-.238-1.322-.352-1.964-.352zM81.828.467h3.77l-5.98 17.85h-4.07L69.578.466h3.772l3.312 10.62c.182.632.38 1.356.572 2.195.19.836.316 1.408.368 1.737.087-.75.387-2.05.902-3.932L81.828.468zM97.072 18.316h-10.14V.466h10.14V3.57h-6.407v3.92h5.964v3.1h-5.965v4.6h6.407v3.126zM105.128 11.467v6.85h-3.732V.466h5.13c2.39 0 4.158.44 5.31 1.326 1.145.882 1.72 2.22 1.72 4.02 0 1.048-.286 1.987-.853 2.802-.57.82-1.376 1.46-2.418 1.925 2.647 4.007 4.37 6.603 5.175 7.773h-4.142l-4.203-6.85-1.987.004zm0-3.077h1.206c1.177 0 2.05-.2 2.612-.596.558-.402.842-1.03.842-1.883 0-.847-.29-1.445-.862-1.806-.573-.36-1.46-.537-2.664-.537h-1.14l.006 4.823z"
                  fill="#414042"></path><ellipse cx="61.024" cy="9.393"
                                                 fill="#F76E20" rx="8.802"
                                                 ry="8.926"></ellipse></g></g></svg></div></span>
                </li>
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-diners-club"><svg
                  height="104" viewBox="0 0 152 104" width="152"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><rect
                  height="104" id="a" rx="12"
                  width="152"></rect></defs><g
                  fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><mask fill="#fff" id="b"><use
                  xlink:href="#a"></use></mask><use
                  fill="#F4F4F4" xlink:href="#a"></use><rect fill="#F4F4F4"
                                                             height="104"
                                                             mask="url(#b)"
                                                             rx="12" width="152"
                                                             x="1"></rect><g
                  transform="translate(42 26)"><ellipse cx="26.716" cy="26"
                                                        fill="#009FDA" rx="26"
                                                        ry="26"></ellipse><path
                  d="M24.116 0c13 0 25.997 11.643 25.997 26 0 14.355-12.997 26-25.997 26V0z"
                  fill="#009FDA"></path><path
                  d="M24.116 52V0H42.75c13 0 25.997 11.643 25.997 26 0 14.355-12.997 26-25.997 26H24.116z"
                  fill="#009FDA"></path><circle cx="25.255" cy="27.139"
                                                fill="#F3F4F4"
                                                r="24.539"></circle><path
                  d="M38.255 24.983c0-7.09-6.34-13.02-11.54-14.583v29.167c5.2-1.563 11.54-7.488 11.54-14.584zM5.916 24.986c0 7.09 6.34 13.02 11.54 14.583V10.4c-5.2 1.565-11.54 7.493-11.54 14.586z"
                  fill="#009FDA"></path></g></g></svg></div></span></li>
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-jcb"><svg
                  clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-miterlimit="1.4" viewBox="0 0 480 301"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path
                  d="M444 0H24C12 0 0 12 0 24v240.1c0 24 12 36 36 36h408c24 0 36-12 36-36v-228C480 12 468 0 444 0z"
                  fill="#f4f4f4"></path><path
                  d="M314.8 174.9h21.5l2.7-.2c4-.8 7.6-4.5 7.6-9.6 0-5-3.5-8.6-7.6-9.6l-2.7-.3h-21.5V175z"
                  fill="#469951" fill-rule="nonzero"></path><path
                  d="M333.9 39.2a37.3 37.3 0 0 0-37.3 37.2v38.7h52.6c1.2 0 2.7 0 3.7.2 11.9.7 20.7 6.8 20.7 17.4 0 8.4-6 15.6-17 17v.4c12 .8 21.3 7.6 21.3 18 0 11.3-10.3 18.7-23.8 18.7h-57.7v75.7h54.7a37.3 37.3 0 0 0 37.2-37.3v-186H334z"
                  fill="#469951" fill-rule="nonzero"></path><path
                  d="M343.9 135.2c0-5-3.5-8.2-7.6-8.8l-2-.2h-19.5v18h19.5c.3 0 1.4 0 2-.2 4.1-.6 7.6-3.9 7.6-8.8z"
                  fill="#469951" fill-rule="nonzero"></path><path
                  d="M128 39.2a37.3 37.3 0 0 0-37.3 37.2v92a73.7 73.7 0 0 0 32.2 8.3c12.8 0 19.8-7.7 19.8-18.4V115h32v43.2c0 16.8-10.5 30.5-46 30.5-21.4 0-38.2-4.7-38.2-4.7v78.4h54.7a37.3 37.3 0 0 0 37.2-37.3V39.2H128z"
                  fill="#245797" fill-rule="nonzero"></path><path
                  d="M231 39.2a37.3 37.3 0 0 0-37.3 37.2v48.8c9.4-8 25.8-13.1 52.2-12 14 .7 29.2 4.6 29.2 4.6v15.8a70.9 70.9 0 0 0-28.2-8.2c-20-1.5-32.1 8.4-32.1 25.5 0 17.4 12 27.3 32 25.6a74.3 74.3 0 0 0 28.3-8.2v15.8s-15 3.9-29.2 4.5c-26.4 1.2-42.8-3.9-52.2-11.9v86h54.6a37.3 37.3 0 0 0 37.3-37.3V39.2h-54.7z"
                  fill="#ca4638" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg></div></span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-checklist-body">
          <div style="">
            <div class="paymentMethod paymentMethod--creditCard">
              <fieldset class="form-fieldset creditCardFieldset">
                <legend class="form-legend is-srOnly">Credit card</legend>
                <div class="form-body">
                  <div class="form-ccFields">
                    <div class="form-field form-field--ccNumber"><label for="ccNumber" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">Credit
                      Card Number</label><input name="ccNumber" autocomplete="cc-number" id="ccNumber" class="form-input optimizedCheckout-form-input has-icon" type="tel" value="">
                      <div class="icon">
                        <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path
                            d="M18 8h-1V6c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5S7 3.24 7 6v2H6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V10c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-6 9c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm3.1-9H8.9V6c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1 1.71 0 3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1v2z"></path>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-field form-field--ccExpiry"><label for="ccExpiry" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">Expiration</label><input name="ccExpiry" autocomplete="cc-exp" id="ccExpiry" placeholder="MM / YY" class="form-input optimizedCheckout-form-input" type="tel" value=""></div>
                    <div class="form-field form-field--ccName"><label for="ccName" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">Name
                      on Card</label><input name="ccName" autocomplete="cc-name" id="ccName" class="form-input optimizedCheckout-form-input" type="text" value=""></div>
                    <div class="form-field form-ccFields-field--ccCvv"><label for="ccCvv" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">CVV<span><span
                      class="has-tip"><div class="icon"><svg height="24"
                                                             viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                                             width="24"
                                                             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path
                      d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 17h-2v-2h2v2zm2.07-7.75l-.9.92C13.45 12.9 13 13.5 13 15h-2v-.5c0-1.1.45-2.1 1.17-2.83l1.24-1.26c.37-.36.59-.86.59-1.41 0-1.1-.9-2-2-2s-2 .9-2 2H8c0-2.21 1.79-4 4-4s4 1.79 4 4c0 .88-.36 1.68-.93 2.25z"></path></svg></div></span></span></label>
                      <input name="ccCvv" autocomplete="cc-csc" id="ccCvv" class="form-input optimizedCheckout-form-input has-icon" type="tel" value="">
                      <div class="icon">
                        <svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path
                            d="M18 8h-1V6c0-2.76-2.24-5-5-5S7 3.24 7 6v2H6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h12c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V10c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm-6 9c-1.1 0-2-.9-2-2s.9-2 2-2 2 .9 2 2-.9 2-2 2zm3.1-9H8.9V6c0-1.71 1.39-3.1 3.1-3.1 1.71 0 3.1 1.39 3.1 3.1v2z"></path>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item">
        <div class="form-checklist-header">
          <div class="form-field"><input name="paymentProviderRadio" class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox" id="radio-paypalexpress" type="radio" value="paypalexpress"><label for="radio-paypalexpress" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label"><img alt="PayPal"
                                                                 class="paymentProviderHeader-img"
                                                                 data-test="payment-method-logo"
                                                                 src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/r-a27911b5d209595e667e9db480b43ab34afcf74d/img/payment-providers/paypalpaymentsprouk.png">
            <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc">
              <ul class="creditCardTypes-list">
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-visa"><svg
                  height="100" viewBox="0 0 148 100" width="148"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g
                  fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path
                  d="M148 84c0 6.6-5.55 12-12 12H12C5.55 96 0 90.6 0 84V12C0 5.4 5.55 0 12 0h124c6.45 0 12 5.4 12 12v72z"
                  fill="#F3F4F4"></path><path
                  d="M0 24V12C0 5.4 5.74 0 12 0h124c6.26 0 12 5.4 12 12v12"
                  fill="#01579F"></path><path
                  d="M148 76v12c0 8.667-5.74 12-12 12H12c-6.26 0-12-3.333-12-12V76"
                  fill="#FAA41D"></path><path
                  d="M55.01 65.267l4.72-29.186h7.546l-4.72 29.19H55.01M89.913 36.8c-1.49-.59-3.85-1.242-6.77-1.242-7.452 0-12.7 3.974-12.73 9.656-.063 4.19 3.756 6.52 6.613 7.918 2.92 1.428 3.913 2.36 3.913 3.633-.04 1.957-2.36 2.857-4.54 2.857-3.014 0-4.628-.465-7.08-1.552l-.996-.466-1.055 6.55c1.77.808 5.03 1.52 8.415 1.553 7.92 0 13.075-3.912 13.137-9.967.03-3.322-1.987-5.868-6.334-7.948-2.64-1.336-4.256-2.236-4.256-3.602.032-1.242 1.367-2.514 4.348-2.514 2.453-.06 4.254.53 5.62 1.12l.684.31L89.91 36.8m10.03 18.13c.62-1.675 3.013-8.165 3.013-8.165-.03.062.62-1.707.994-2.794l.525 2.52s1.428 6.986 1.74 8.445H99.94zm9.317-18.846h-5.84c-1.8 0-3.17.53-3.945 2.424L88.265 65.27h7.918s1.305-3.6 1.585-4.377h9.687c.217 1.024.9 4.377.9 4.377h6.987l-6.082-29.19zm-60.555 0l-7.39 19.904-.807-4.037c-1.37-4.652-5.653-9.713-10.435-12.23l6.77 25.52h7.98L56.68 36.09H48.7"
                  fill="#3B5CAA"></path><path
                  d="M34.454 36.08H22.312l-.124.59c9.47 2.423 15.744 8.26 18.32 15.277L37.87 38.534c-.436-1.863-1.77-2.39-3.416-2.453"
                  fill="#F8A51D"></path></g></svg></div></span></li>
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-mastercard"><svg
                  viewBox="0 0 131.39 86.9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path
                  d="M48.37 15.14h34.66v56.61H48.37z" fill="#ff5f00"></path><path
                  d="M51.94 43.45a35.94 35.94 0 0113.75-28.3 36 36 0 100 56.61 35.94 35.94 0 01-13.75-28.31z"
                  fill="#eb001b"></path><path
                  d="M120.5 65.76V64.6h.5v-.24h-1.19v.24h.47v1.16zm2.31 0v-1.4h-.36l-.42 1-.42-1h-.36v1.4h.26V64.7l.39.91h.27l.39-.91v1.06zM123.94 43.45a36 36 0 01-58.25 28.3 36 36 0 000-56.61 36 36 0 0158.25 28.3z"
                  fill="#f79e1b"></path></svg></div></span></li>
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-discover"><svg
                  height="104" viewBox="0 0 152 104" width="152"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><rect
                  height="104" id="a" rx="12"
                  width="152"></rect></defs><g
                  fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><mask fill="#fff" id="b"><use
                  xlink:href="#a"></use></mask><use
                  fill="#F4F4F4" xlink:href="#a"></use><rect fill="#F4F4F4"
                                                             height="104"
                                                             mask="url(#b)"
                                                             rx="12" width="152"
                                                             x="1"></rect><path
                  d="M70.553 104H149c2.21 0 4-1.783 4-4.007V46.597C142.305 71.907 111.28 93.04 70.553 104z"
                  fill="#F76E20" mask="url(#b)"></path><g mask="url(#b)"
                                                          transform="translate(19 42)"><path
                  d="M14.763 9.22c0 2.94-.824 5.19-2.47 6.752-1.652 1.56-4.035 2.344-7.15 2.344H.155V.466H5.68c2.876 0 5.106.772 6.69 2.31C13.97 4.31 14.764 6.46 14.764 9.22zm-3.876.1c0-3.834-1.672-5.75-5.004-5.75h-1.99v11.62h1.602c3.596.002 5.392-1.957 5.392-5.87zM17.51 18.316V.466h3.733v17.85H17.51zM34.774 13.608c0 1.616-.57 2.88-1.718 3.81-1.146.927-2.734 1.397-4.773 1.397-1.874 0-3.54-.36-4.987-1.074v-3.516c1.19.543 2.196.915 3.017 1.14.822.218 1.577.327 2.26.327.815 0 1.446-.16 1.882-.475.43-.313.657-.792.657-1.413 0-.35-.095-.66-.292-.933-.188-.277-.474-.54-.85-.79-.374-.25-1.134-.657-2.28-1.21-1.073-.512-1.877-1.008-2.42-1.477-.542-.47-.967-1.018-1.288-1.65-.32-.63-.48-1.363-.48-2.2 0-1.577.526-2.818 1.582-3.72 1.06-.908 2.514-1.356 4.38-1.356.913 0 1.787.108 2.617.328.83.217 1.702.53 2.607.927l-1.203 2.942c-.94-.39-1.72-.67-2.334-.818-.616-.153-1.22-.232-1.81-.232-.71 0-1.254.164-1.627.502-.38.334-.567.768-.567 1.305 0 .335.076.623.23.875.152.25.395.487.728.72.332.23 1.125.647 2.366 1.25 1.643.8 2.77 1.6 3.384 2.4.613.796.92 1.778.92 2.943zM46.018 3.62c-1.406 0-2.49.54-3.263 1.605C41.98 6.295 41.6 7.79 41.6 9.7c0 3.978 1.473 5.97 4.418 5.97 1.238 0 2.727-.305 4.492-.94v3.175c-1.446.613-3.06.916-4.842.916-2.56 0-4.52-.79-5.875-2.367-1.357-1.572-2.034-3.834-2.034-6.782 0-1.855.335-3.48 1.003-4.874.662-1.402 1.623-2.467 2.87-3.212C42.884.84 44.345.467 46.022.467c1.71 0 3.43.42 5.152 1.258l-1.203 3.077c-.663-.317-1.32-.592-1.99-.83-.67-.238-1.322-.352-1.964-.352zM81.828.467h3.77l-5.98 17.85h-4.07L69.578.466h3.772l3.312 10.62c.182.632.38 1.356.572 2.195.19.836.316 1.408.368 1.737.087-.75.387-2.05.902-3.932L81.828.468zM97.072 18.316h-10.14V.466h10.14V3.57h-6.407v3.92h5.964v3.1h-5.965v4.6h6.407v3.126zM105.128 11.467v6.85h-3.732V.466h5.13c2.39 0 4.158.44 5.31 1.326 1.145.882 1.72 2.22 1.72 4.02 0 1.048-.286 1.987-.853 2.802-.57.82-1.376 1.46-2.418 1.925 2.647 4.007 4.37 6.603 5.175 7.773h-4.142l-4.203-6.85-1.987.004zm0-3.077h1.206c1.177 0 2.05-.2 2.612-.596.558-.402.842-1.03.842-1.883 0-.847-.29-1.445-.862-1.806-.573-.36-1.46-.537-2.664-.537h-1.14l.006 4.823z"
                  fill="#414042"></path><ellipse cx="61.024" cy="9.393"
                                                 fill="#F76E20" rx="8.802"
                                                 ry="8.926"></ellipse></g></g></svg></div></span>
                </li>
                <li class="creditCardTypes-list-item"><span class="cardIcon"><div
                  class="icon cardIcon-icon icon--medium"
                  data-test="credit-card-icon-american-express"><svg height="104"
                                                                     viewBox="0 0 156 104"
                                                                     width="156"
                                                                     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g
                  fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path
                  d="M144 104H12c-6.15 0-12-5.85-12-12V12C0 5.85 5.85 0 12 0h132c6.15 0 12 5.85 12 12v80c0 6.15-5.85 12-12 12z"
                  fill="#60C7EE"></path><g fill="#FFF"><path
                  d="M95.05 46.532v3.68h12.93v4.723H95.05V59.5h12.79l5.244-6.824-4.673-6.144H95.05m-59.707 9.382h5.906l-2.97-8.324-2.94 8.324"></path><path
                  d="M128.833 52.77l11.29-15.125h-19.067l-2.536 3.9-2.608-3.9h-46.59l-1.254 4.224-1.264-4.227H31.27L17.72 68.687h17.326l1.31-3.822h3.824l1.345 3.822h73.594l3.28-4.594 3.28 4.594h19.36l-4.867-6.343-7.342-9.574zM83.185 64.744H76.38v-17.66l-5.243 17.66h-6.16l-5.233-17.66v17.66H44.318l-1.345-3.823H33.54l-1.312 3.826h-8.483L33.85 41.588h9.065L52.94 64.56V41.59h10.927l4.214 14.09 4.187-14.09h10.92v23.156zm40.524 0l-5.31-7.44-5.31 7.44H86.72V41.588h27.085l4.76 7.124 4.63-7.124h9.062l-8.37 11.215 9.16 11.94h-9.338z"></path></g></g></svg></div></span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </label></div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item">
        <div class="form-checklist-header">
          <div class="form-field"><input name="paymentProviderRadio" class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox" id="radio-affirm" type="radio" value="affirm"><label for="radio-affirm" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label"><img
            alt="Affirm" class="paymentProviderHeader-img"
            data-test="payment-method-logo"
            src="https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/r-a27911b5d209595e667e9db480b43ab34afcf74d/img/payment-providers/affirm-checkout-header.png"><span
            class="paymentProviderHeader-name" data-test="payment-method-name">Monthly Payments</span>
            <div class="paymentProviderHeader-cc"></div>
          </label></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="form-body">.form-body</div>
</form>
```

Comment: i am not sure i have to test it thank you for answering i will let you know here in  a moment

Comment: no it doesnt seem to work :( thanks for trying though

Comment: actually yes it does work !! there are a few things that i am wanting to change though, for example instead of being a button i just want it to be an onload event

Comment: it is working but there are many form-body throughout the rest of the checklist as well as all the other div classes, how can i make it to work with the <ul> or <li>

Comment: <script>
window.onload = function replaceFormBodyWithIframe () {
  let formBody = document.querySelector('.checkout-view-content.checkout-view-content-enter-done');
  
  let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = 'example.com';
  iframe.style.border = '1px solid gray';
  iframe.width = '450px';
  iframe.height = '450px';
  formBody.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', iframe);
  formBody.remove();
}
</script>
<style>
.checkout-view-content.checkout-view-content-enter-done {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
</style>

Comment: i been having success testing this one in w3 but for some reason it is not working when i add it to my bigcommerce test website. i tried your revised answer but it grays out the background and has <form></form> tags outside the areas i am trying to remove (ie above the payment section and below the place order button) i am trying to be below the payment section and above the place order button '

Comment: i been getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentElement' of null
    at replaceFormBodyWithIframe

Comment: @TestCustomer `null` means it was unable to find a <div class="form-body"> containing the text "Credit Card". A link to the page would help.

Comment: i am also getting this error: checkout:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
    at findFormBodyWithCreditCard (checkout:17)
    at replaceFormBodyWithIframe (checkout:35)  here is the full html of the page: https://pastebin.com/tiGJFRvk

Comment: i been tinkering with it all day and still cant get it to work

Comment: i use this with no errors but it still doesnt work https://pastebin.com/E4deGTg7